# How can I rotate only jpg and jpeg on upload?

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick

Below I have a very simple upload script that uploads images in png, jpg and jpeg formats.

I know that png images will maintain orientation as that file has no information about its orientation.
However, when uploading jpg or jpeg a portrait image is rotated by 90 degrees anti-clockwise.

**How can I rotate only the jpg and jpeg to have the correct orientation?**

P.s This upload script also updates the image path into MySQL

Many thanks for any help!

```
<?php

if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {
   $errors = array();
   $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
   $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
   $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
   $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
   $file_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));
   $img_path = ("images/".$file_name);
   $expensions = array("jpeg","jpg","png");

   if (in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false) {
       $errors[] = "extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
   }

   if ($file_size > 2097152) {
       $errors[] = 'File too large';
   }

   if (empty($errors) == true) {
       // connect to the database
       $servername = 'HOST';
       $username = 'USER';
       $password = 'PASS';
       $dbname = 'TABLE';
       $current_user = $_SESSION['user_name'];

       try {
           $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
           // set the PDO error mode to exception
           $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

           $sql = "UPDATE users SET image_name='$file_name', image_size='$file_size', image_path='$img_path'  WHERE user_id = $current_user";

           // Prepare statement
           $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

           // execute the query
           $stmt->execute();

           // echo a message to say the UPDATE succeeded
           echo "";
       } catch(PDOException $e) {
           echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
       }

       $conn = null;

       move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
       echo "";
   } else {
       print_r($errors);
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: you could try looking into php manual on imagerotate http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [imagerotate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php) php function.

```
$degrees = 90; //required value here
$img_path = ("images/".$file_name);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);
$extension = substr(strrchr($file_name,'.'),1);

if ($extension == jpg || $extension == jpeg)
{
imagejpeg($rotate);
}
imagedestroy($source); //free memory
imagedestroy($rotate);
```

Comment: Got this working, however it only works on phones and not on larger devices.